# implementing interface

Tags: java, interface

hello guys so i have this assignment that i need to implement interface to go over an ArrayList and sort it (ascending or descnding).I dont want "the" answer i just need some suggestions on my approach and why i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Week7.Check cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
 at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
 at Week7.TestCheck.main(TestCheck.java:18)
```

This is how i did it:

comparable had one method called `public int compairTo(Object o)`:

```
public class Check implements comparable {
    private Integer checkNumber;

    public Check(Integer newCheckNumber) {
        setCheckNumber(newCheckNumber);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getCheckNumber().toString();
    }

    public void setCheckNumber(Integer checkNumber) {
        this.checkNumber = checkNumber;
    }

    public Integer getCheckNumber() {
        return checkNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public int compairTo(Object o) {
        Check compair = (Check) o;
        int result = 0;
        if (this.getCheckNumber() > compair.getCheckNumber())
            result = 1;

        else if (this.getCheckNumber() < compair.getCheckNumber())
            result = -1;

        return result;
    }
}
```

in my main i had this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class TestCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList checkList = new ArrayList();

        checkList.add(new Check(445));
        checkList.add(new Check(101));
        checkList.add(new Check(110));
        checkList.add(new Check(553));
        checkList.add(new Check(123));

        Collections.sort(checkList);

        for (int i = 0; i < checkList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(checkList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant the tag java instead of javascript, so I retagged it.

Comment: please remember to put your code in a code block

Comment: I am not sure if it is just an error in copying, but I believe that it should be Comparable not comparable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `Comparator` ( what you call with two arguments )  you have to pass it as a parameter to the `Collections.sort` method.

Like this:

```
Collections.sort( checkList, new Comparator<Check>() {
    public int compare( Check one, Check two ) {
        return one.getCheckNumber() - two.getCheckNumber();
    }
 });
```

This is how it would look like:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Check   {
    private final Integer checkNumber;

    public Check(Integer newCheckNumber) {
        this.checkNumber = newCheckNumber;
    }
    public Integer getCheckNumber() {
        return this.checkNumber;
    }
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        List<Check> list = new ArrayList<Check>();

        list.add(new Check(445));
        list.add(new Check(101));
        list.add(new Check(110));
        list.add(new Check(553));
        list.add(new Check(123));

        Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Check>() {
           public int compare( Check one, Check two ){
               return one.getCheckNumber() - two.getCheckNumber();
           } 
        });
        for( Check item : list ) {
            System.out.println( item.getCheckNumber() );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

C'mon - Java is case sensitive.  "comparable" is not the same as "Comparable"

```
public class Check implements comparable
```

Spelling matters as well.  "compairTo" isn't the same method as "compareTo"

```
@Override
public int compairTo(Object o) {
```

Comment: yes  you are correct i found my mistake thank you very much and im sorry for the miss tag ^^:

Comment: i miss spelled it... the only problem is it didnt say why in a clear way.

Comment: @1ace1 you should hit the check mark on this answer if it's the one that solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the interface **comparable** you implements is not the interface **java.lang.Comparable**， their name might be the same, but the package?

Answer (score 0):

when you implement an interface you must use the method signature provided by the interface, exactly as it is defined in the interface:

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
```

Also you might like to parameterize the List eg. `List<Comparable>`, and the Comparable eg. `Comparable<Check>` as using generics is a compile time technique which would have identified your misspellings

Comment: ok how would i do it if im going to use Comparator with 2 arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you pass to `Arrays.sort()` must implement `Comparable`, which is a java system interface. You probably want to throw away `comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

> *[...And] why i get this error*

When you call:

```
Collections.sort(checkList);
```

In line 18, the method is expecting that your elements implement `Comparable` ( to be able to compare them )  You might not know this, but that's how it works ( as specified in the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) )

> *All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface*

Then the method runs, it tries to "cast" your objects to the type `Comparable` since your class doesn't implements it, it throws `ClassCastException`

To better understand this, try the following code:

```
class Some {
}
class Test {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
         Runnable r = ( Runnable ) new Some();
    }
}
```

If you analyze the line you may think *"Why are you trying to assign a Runnable from Some? They are not related!"*

And you're right, let's see the output:

```
$ java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Some cannot be cast to java.lang.Runnable
        at Test.main(A.java:5)
```

Same error message.  You may take a look at line 5 and see the cast.

That's exactly what it's happening in the `Collections.sort`  method, but with `Comparable`

Comment: ok how would i do it if im going to use Comparator with 2 arguments?

Comment: @1ace1 didn't duffymo answered your question?

Comment: @1ace1 I added a new answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841284/implementing-interface/2844404#2844404